# function query() on a non-object in config.php

Tags: php, database, class

i have class like this in my config.php file

```
class Config {

    public static $__db = array(
        "host"     => 'l',
        "username" => 'u',
        "password" => 'p',
        "database" => 'x'
    );
}
```

and when i try to add this

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY `id` ASC");

$ad = array();
while($row = $db->fetchAll($q))
{
    $ad[] = $row;
}
```

i always get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /
```

how i ca solve this please ?

Comment: Did you connect to DB before that line?

Comment: `var_dump` your `$db` var and check what's in it.

Comment: What relevance is the `Config` class you quoted to the `$db->query` line you're having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try include your config file where you call the function

```
$db = new config(); // create class object
$db->query() //call class method
```

or try this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php